# How to get subclusters from the function aheatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm using [aheatmap in the NMF package](http://nmf.r-forge.r-project.org/aheatmap.html) to construct heat maps of array and RNA-seq data.

I'm trying to extract subclusters of data in the same way that [this user was trying to use cutree to extract from hclust objects](https://www.biostars.org/p/86563/)

I can't seem to find an attribute of the aheatmap object that is of type hclust or interpreble by cutree. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've also posted this both here and in BioStar, because it's not entirely an R question and it's not entirely a bioinformatics question.

A few things I've tried:

```
library(NMF)
#create some data
d <- matrix(rnorm(120),12,10)
# cluster it
heatmp.obj = aheatmap(d) 
# define some clusters
mycl <- cutree(heatmp.obj$Rowv, k=2) #this produces an error
mycl <- cutree(heatmp.obj$Colv, k=2) #this produces an error
```

Answer (score 3):

aheatmap returns a list, two elements of which are type 'dendrogram'. 'dendrogram' can be coerced to type 'hclust' using `as.hclust()`. For instance,

`a = cutree(as.hclust(heatmp.obj$Rowv), k=3)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example in the second link you provided:

```
d <- matrix(rnorm(120),12,10)
hr <- hclust(dist(d, method="euclidean"), method="complete")
mycl <- cutree(hr, k=2)
heatmp.obj <- aheatmap(d,Rowv=as.dendrogram(hr))
```

Does that get you closer to your desired answer?

**EDIT**
Image with `aheatmap`:
[image]

Image with `hclust`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @desc! I'd prefer to do it in a way that relies on aheatmap's default clustering algorithm, rather than specifying with hclust and then using that in aheatmap. Does that make sense? In other words, running `heatmp.obj = aheatmap(d,Rowv=as.dendrogram(hr))` doesn't yield the same display item as `heatmp.obj = aheatmap(d)`

Comment: Is there an `as.hclust()`?

Comment: @Atticus29, I updated the hclust based on `aheatmap` defaults, the resulting clusters appear the same, though the clades may rotate around branches.

Comment: Thanks again, @desc! Is there any way to enforce the same order of the branches? Asking because I have tons of arguments passed to aheatmap that I can't pass to hclust, so the only way hclust would be helpful would be if it can mimic the clustering and order of the dendrogram generated by aheatmap exactly.

Comment: @Atticus29, I believe if you want the same display as before, you can use `heatmp.obj = aheatmap(d)`. The results from `hr <- hclust(dist(d, method="euclidean"), method="complete")` should be the same (using the same clustering/distance functions), but will let you now cut `hr` instead of trying to cut your heatmap object.

Comment: Actually, it does seem like there is an as.hclust() coercion!

Comment: nice find! that should make things easier.